# compile time error in function which inserting the text into image.(steganography)

Tags: java, swing, steganography

I am building a standalone application which hides the text onto the image (Stenography)

I am novice and facing error while implementing the fuction of GridBagLayout

Here , is the following algo which I am using with the errors
**(I have mentioned all the errors in comments i.e. //ERROR:.........)**

```
  import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.Container;
    import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
    import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
    import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;


    public class Steganography_View extends JFrame
    {
        //sie variables for window
        private static int WIDTH  = 500;
        private static int HEIGHT = 400;

        //elements for JPanel
        private JTextArea   input;
        private JScrollBar  scroll,scroll2;
        private JButton     encodeButton,decodeButton;
        private JLabel      image_input;

        //elements for Menu
        private JMenu       file;
        private JMenuItem   encode;
        private JMenuItem   decode;
        private JMenuItem   exit;


        public Steganography_View(String name)
        {
            //set the title of the JFrame
            super(name);

            //Menubar
            JMenuBar menu = new JMenuBar();

            JMenu file = new JMenu("File"); file.setMnemonic('F');
            encode = new JMenuItem("Encode"); encode.setMnemonic('E'); file.add(encode);
            decode = new JMenuItem("Decode"); decode.setMnemonic('D'); file.add(decode);
            file.addSeparator();
            exit = new JMenuItem("Exit"); exit.setMnemonic('x'); file.add(exit);

            menu.add(file);
            setJMenuBar(menu);

            // display rules
            setResizable(true);                     //allow window to be resized: true?false
            setBackground(Color.lightGray);         //background color of window: Color(int,int,int) or Color.name
            setLocation(100,100);                   //location on the screen to display window
            setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//what to do on close operation: exit, do_nothing, etc
            setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);                  //set the size of the window
            setVisible(true);                       //show the window: true?false
        }


        public JMenuItem    getEncode()     { return encode;            }

        public JMenuItem    getDecode()     { return decode;            }

        public JMenuItem    getExit()       { return exit;              }

        public JTextArea    getText()       { return input;             }

        public JLabel       getImageInput() { return image_input;       }

        public JPanel       getTextPanel()  { return new Text_Panel();  }

        public JPanel       getImagePanel() { return new Image_Panel(); }

        public JButton      getEButton()    { return encodeButton;      }

        public JButton      getDButton()    { return decodeButton;      }


        private class Text_Panel extends JPanel
        {

            public Text_Panel()
            {
                //setup GridBagLayout
                GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout(); 
                GridBagConstraints layoutConstraints = new GridBagConstraints(); 
                setLayout(layout);

                input = new JTextArea();
                layoutConstraints.gridx     = 0; layoutConstraints.gridy = 0; 
                layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 1; layoutConstraints.gridheight = 1; 
                layoutConstraints.fill      = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
                layoutConstraints.insets    = new Insets(0,0,0,0); 
                layoutConstraints.anchor    = GridBagConstraints.CENTER; 
                layoutConstraints.weightx   = 1.0; layoutConstraints.weighty = 50.0;
                JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(input,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,

//Error;The constructor JScrollPane(JTextArea, int, int) is undefined

                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);//Error;The constructor JScrollPane(JTextArea, int, int) is undefined
                layout.setConstraints(scroll,layoutConstraints);//Error;The method setConstraints(Component, GridBagConstraints) in the type GridBagLayout is not applicable for the arguments (JScrollPane, GridBagConstraints)
                scroll.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));// Error;The method setConstraints(Component, GridBagConstraints) in the type GridBagLayout is not applicable for the arguments (JScrollPane, GridBagConstraints)
                add(scroll);//Error;The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JScrollPane)

                encodeButton = new JButton("Encode Now");
                layoutConstraints.gridx     = 0; layoutConstraints.gridy = 1; 
                layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 1; layoutConstraints.gridheight = 1; 
                layoutConstraints.fill      = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
                layoutConstraints.insets    = new Insets(0,-5,-5,-5); 
                layoutConstraints.anchor    = GridBagConstraints.CENTER; 
                layoutConstraints.weightx   = 1.0; layoutConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
                layout.setConstraints(encodeButton,layoutConstraints);//Error;The method setConstraints(Component, GridBagConstraints) in the type GridBagLayout is not applicable for the arguments (JButton, GridBagConstraints)
                add(encodeButton);//Error;The method setConstraints(Component, GridBagConstraints) in the type GridBagLayout is not applicable for the arguments (JButton, GridBagConstraints)

                //set basic display
                setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));//Error;The method setBorder(Border) is undefined for the type Steganography_View.Text_Panel
            }
        }


        private class Image_Panel extends JPanel
        {

            public Image_Panel()
            {
                //setup GridBagLayout
                GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout(); 
                GridBagConstraints layoutConstraints = new GridBagConstraints(); 
                setLayout(layout);

                image_input = new JLabel();
                layoutConstraints.gridx     = 0; layoutConstraints.gridy = 0; 
                layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 1; layoutConstraints.gridheight = 1; 
                layoutConstraints.fill      = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
                layoutConstraints.insets    = new Insets(0,0,0,0); 
                layoutConstraints.anchor    = GridBagConstraints.CENTER; 
                layoutConstraints.weightx   = 1.0; layoutConstraints.weighty = 50.0;
                JScrollPane scroll2 = new JScrollPane(image_input,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,//Error;The constructor JScrollPane(JLabel, int, int) is undefined
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);//Error;The constructor JScrollPane(JLabel, int, int) is undefined
                layout.setConstraints(scroll2,layoutConstraints);//Error;The method setConstraints(Component, GridBagConstraints) in the type GridBagLayout is not applicable for the arguments (JScrollPane, GridBagConstraints)
                scroll2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));//Error;The method setBorder(Border) is undefined for the type JScrollPane
                image_input.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                add(scroll2);//Error;The method setBorder(Border) is undefined for the type JScrollPane

                decodeButton = new JButton("Decode Now");
                layoutConstraints.gridx     = 0; layoutConstraints.gridy = 1; 
                layoutConstraints.gridwidth = 1; layoutConstraints.gridheight = 1; 
                layoutConstraints.fill      = GridBagConstraints.BOTH; 
                layoutConstraints.insets    = new Insets(0,-5,-5,-5); 
                layoutConstraints.anchor    = GridBagConstraints.CENTER; 
                layoutConstraints.weightx   = 1.0; layoutConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
                layout.setConstraints(decodeButton,layoutConstraints);//Error;The method setConstraints(Component, GridBagConstraints) in the type GridBagLayout is not applicable for the arguments (JButton, GridBagConstraints)
                add(decodeButton);//Error;The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JButton)

                //set basic display
                setBackground(Color.lightGray);
                setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));//Error;The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JButton)
            }
         }


        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            new Steganography_View("Secure Data Transmission");
        }
    }
```

Please Help me to debug this.

Comment: mentioning the error you get might also help.

Comment: yes i have updated ..it with error

Comment: Java's error messages are generally very good.  Make an effort to actually read and understand them.

Comment: (Hint:  Start with the first error message and work through in order, recompiling after you fix each one.  Very often when you fix one problem it eliminates a bunch of errors, and often the later errors are less informative than the first one.)

Comment: Please take a look at JavaDocs as they can clearly direct you to the solution of these errors.

Answer (score 2):

**Use the Java documentation in your favor, so you can clearly know how its library methods work. [The complete documentation can be found here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html)**

Your struggle can be seen as pure lazyness or lack of knowledge regarding [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html) (JavaDocs).

Please take a look at your errors as they clearly direct you to the solution.

**Examples:**

---

> The constructor JScrollPane(JTextArea, int, int) is undefined.

[JScrollPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) has [four constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#JScrollPane(java.awt.Component,%20int,%20int)).

- `public JScrollPane()`
- `public JScrollPane(Component view)`
- `public JScrollPane(Component view, int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy)`
- `public JScrollPane(int vsbPolicy, int hsbPolicy)`

You need to use one of the provided ones to build your object, otherwise it will not work...

---

> The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (JButton)

Please take a look at the [Component documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component)) to see how to use the `add()` method...

---

> The method setConstraints(Component, GridBagConstraints) in the type GridBagLayout is not applicable for the arguments (JScrollPane, GridBagConstraints)

You have provided arguments different than the expected ones for the `setConstraints` method of `GridBagLayout`, as you passed different arguments than the ones [clearly explained here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html#setConstraints(java.awt.Component,%20java.awt.GridBagConstraints)):

`public void setConstraints(Component comp, GridBagConstraints constraints)`

- `comp` - the component to be modified
- `constraints` - the constraints to be applied

---

... and so on.